Good alternative to Pygame for C++ Development?
I have been developing demos in pygame (a python library) for quite some time, but with the impending conclusion of my latest project I'm looking to jump ship to C++. I did some simple programs in that language a while back and it seems like the prospects of coding in it are a little greener.
I figure that I can look into some OpenGL tutorials to get things rendering (I did some toying with OpenGL in the past, but fell out of practice), but this seems like it will leave me without many of pygame's helpful image-processing tools (for instance, chroma-key on loaded images, or drawing multiple small textures onto a large canvas). As such, I would like to find another library that can patch in these functions.
If my assertions are correct, what would you recommend to replace the absent functions? Or if I am wrong, are there any documents or tutorials you'd recommend to learn what I'm lacking?
